# MVC5 on IIS 7.5 throws an exception: Could not load type HttpRedirect

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc-5, http-redirect

I have MVC5 app deployed fine to local IIS8 (Windows 8) but not working after deployment to Windows Web Server 2008 SP1.

The error I get:

```
Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Could not load type 'HttpRedirect'.
Stack Trace: 
[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'HttpRedirect'.]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +9671464
   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load type 'HttpRedirect'.]
   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +359
   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, Boolean checkAptcaBit) +19
   System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry.SecureGetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +39
   System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry..ctor(String name, String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +42
   System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1 moduleList) +160
   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext) +950
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +82
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296
[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'HttpRedirect'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9915300
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

I went through multiple articles and checked settings on IIS, Reinstalled NET frameworks (4, 4.5, 4.5.1), registered within IIS using: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir

I tried as well deploying few different test applications using standard ASP.NET website, MVC2/3/4 and 5. All end up with this same error. Win-forms using NET 4 work fine on this server.

What is interesting I cannot find any directly related article on the net to problem with loading 'HttpRedirect' type. There is HttpRedirect role installed on the server.

Not sure what to do next. Fight is going on second day and I am running out of ideas. It is not easy to find detailed requirements for MVC to run on the machine either, or it's just me and Friday :-)

UPDATE:

log from FUSLOGVW

> *** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (27/06/2014 @ 15:20:31) ***
>
> The operation was successful. Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation
>   completed successfully.
>
> Assembly manager loaded from: 
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Running under
>   executable  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
>   --- A detailed error log follows.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.Http  (Partial) WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an
>   assembly: WRN: Assembly Name: System.Web.Http | Domain ID: 6 WRN: A
>   partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is
>   provided. WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect
>   assembly. WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual
>   identity for the assembly, WRN: that consists of the simple name,
>   version, culture, and public key token. WRN: See whitepaper
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and
>   common solutions to this issue. LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///D:/sitesource/mysite/CM3Management/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath =
>   D:\sitesource\mysite\CM3Management\bin LOG: Dynamic Base =
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\cm3management\bf917f7b LOG: Cache Base =
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\cm3management\bf917f7b LOG: AppName = 871e80 Calling assembly :
>   (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file:
>   D:\sitesource\mysite\CM3Management\web.config LOG: Using host
>   configuration file:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config LOG: Using
>   machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private,
>   custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files/cm3management/bf917f7b/871e80/System.Web.Http.DLL. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files/cm3management/bf917f7b/871e80/System.Web.Http/System.Web.Http.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///D:/sitesource/mysite/CM3Management/bin/System.Web.Http.DLL.
>   LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file:
>   D:\sitesource\mysite\CM3Management\bin\System.Web.Http.dll LOG:
>   Entering download cache setup phase. LOG: Assembly Name is:
>   System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 LOG: A partially-specified assembly
>   bind succeeded from the application directory. Need to re-apply
>   policy. LOG: Using application configuration file:
>   D:\sitesource\mysite\CM3Management\web.config LOG: Using host
>   configuration file:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config LOG: Using
>   machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 LOG: GAC Lookup was
>   unsuccessful. LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\cm3management\bf917f7b\871e80\assembly\dl3\4ba23522\3f728a19_6f7acf01\System.Web.Http.dll.
>   LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.

Similar issue "partially loaded assembly" affects more assemblies that System.Web.Http only in my case. So far all I checked have similar looking log.

I wanted to add as well that I tried publish with "copy local" turned on and then off for System.Web.Http assembly. It makes no difference. Copy local for all assemblies does not help either.

Comment: Can you run `fuslogvw` on the server and see if there are issues with the lookup paths? Sounds to me like a DLL is being missed or loading a bad version.

Comment: Thank you for comment Brad. There is light in the tunnel as the log says something about partially loaded assembly. Not sure what it is yet. I have attached log to the main post for now if you wish to have a look.

Comment: So it looks like `System.Web.Http` is to blame. At compile time, do you see any warnings about "Found conflicts between different versions of the same assembly ..."? VS2013 gives some nice information about this kind of things and makes specifying the `<dependentAssembly>` really easy. Ideally you should have something like `<dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" /></dependentAssembly>` in `<assemblyBinding>` node.

Comment: Also, assuming this gets resolved, make sure to disable `fuslogvw`. It's a lot of overhead, so best to eliminate it after it has served its purpose.

Comment: I deploy it to the other machine. My local one runs windows 8 and the app works fine when deployed into local IIS8. After deployment it breaks on the testing environment only.